# How to create a public static variable that is modifiable only from their class?

Tags: java, class, static, member, public

I have two classes:

```
class a {
    public static int var;
    private int getVar() {
        return var; //Yes
    }
    private void setVar(int var) {
        a.var = var; //Yes
    }
}


class b {
    private int getVar() {
        return a.var; //Yes
    }
    private void setVar(int var) {
        a.var = var; //No
    }
}
```

Q: Can i make modifiable member only from his class, for other classes  would be constant ?

Comment: make the setter private

Comment: If the *class defining it can modify that field*, then it is NOT a *constant*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the `public` access modifier basically allows you to modify the value of the reference from anywhere in your code base.

What you can do is have a `private` or less-restricted access modifier according to your specific needs, and then implement a getter, but no setter.

In the latter case, remember to add some logic to prevent mutable objects, such as collections, from being mutated.

**Example**

```
class Foo {
    // primitive, immutable
    private int theInt = 42;
    public int getTheInt() {
        return theInt;
    }
    // Object, immutable
    private String theString = "42";
    public String getTheString() {
        return theString;
    }
    // mutable!
    private StringBuilder theSB = new StringBuilder("42");
    public StringBuilder getTheSB() {
        // wrapping around
        return new StringBuilder(theSB);
    }
    // mutable!
    // java 7+ diamond syntax here
    private Map<String, String> theMap = new HashMap<>();
    {
        theMap.put("the answer is", "42");
    }
    public Map<String, String> getTheMap() {
        // will throw UnsupportedOperationException if you 
        // attempt to mutate through the getter
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(theMap);
    }
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: I know that I need to create a private variable and public getter. I wanted to know if it could be another way but thank you :)

Comment: @Kumas.r.o you're welcome. And yeah, that's the only way unless you set your field `final`, which is probably not what you're looking for here.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `setter` and make variable `private`. Then other class only can read the value stetted.

```
public class a {
 private static int var=2;
 public static int getVar() {
    return var; 
 }
}
```

But when you come to `Java` `reflection` there is no such protection.

Answer (score 0):

The answer Is **NO** you can't make a public static variable only modified from its class you can make the variable **private** and has only public getter or you can add setter **private**